# Mixing graphite outputs in a alert from bosun

Tags: expression, alert, graphite, bosun

I am working on getting bosun up and running and i ran into the following issue.

I have the following alert

```
alert total_logins.graphite {

$blue_login = "sumSeries(SESAM.AUDIT.P.AUTH1_SESPL_AUDIT_ING_SES_PL.blue_*.LOGIN.graph)"
$blue_login_hist = graphiteBand($blue_login, "5m","7d", "",4)
$blue_login_now = graphite($blue_login, "5m", "", "")
$blue_login_hist_med = median($blue_login_hist)
$blue_login_now_med = median($blue_login_now)
$blue_login_1 = $blue_login_now_med/$blue_login_hist_med

$orange_login = "sumSeries(SESAM.AUDIT.P.AUTH1_SESPL_AUDIT_ING_SES_PL.orange_*.LOGIN.graph)"
$orange_login_hist = graphiteBand($orange_login, "5m","7d", "",4)
$orange_login_now = graphite($orange_login, "5m", "", "")
$orange_login_hist_med = median($orange_login_hist)
$orange_login_now_med = median($orange_login_now)
$orange_login_1 = $orange_login_now_med/$orange_login_hist_med

crit =  $orange_login_1 < 0.5 || $blue_login_1 < 0.5}
```

I do not get any errors but it also shows no output when i run it thru Rule Editor testing. When i use 1 or the other variable it works fine like this

```
crit =  $orange_login_1 < 0.5
```

Or the blue one. Both on there own work. But i want to create a multi layerd critical.
I have read the documentation but have not figured it out.

Any suggestions will help.
Marcel